# How to get total stock of items in different table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have Item and StockLocation tables. Item's table contains:

- ItemID
- Code
- Name
- Stock (not mapped to table but exist in Item's entity)

and StockLocation's table contains:

- StockLocationID
- ItemID
- LocationID
- Stock

I want to display the items data with its stock. How LINQ code to get total stock per items?

**UPDATE**
What I want to achieve, if it is in sql query:

```
select i.ItemID, i.Code, i.Name, SUM(sl.stock) as total from Item i inner join StockLocation sl on i.ItemID = sl.ItemID
group by i.ItemID, i.Code, i.Name
```

and this is what I've tried:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
    var query = context.Items.Include(i => i.StockLocations).AsNoTracking().Where(i => i.RowStatus == true);
    query.GroupBy(i => i.ItemID).Sum(?)
    return query.OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList();
}
```

I cannot access the StockLocation's stock in Sum method

**UPDATE 2:**
based on @just.another.programmer answer, I modified the query into:

```
var query = from i in context.Items.Include(i => i.Category).Include(i => i.Unit).Include(i => i.StockLocations).AsNoTracking()
            join sl in context.StockLocations on i.ItemID equals sl.ItemID
            where i.RowStatus == true
            group sl by i into slg
            select new Item()
            {
                ItemID = slg.Key.ItemID,
                Code = slg.Key.Code,
                Name = slg.Key.Name,
                CategoryID = slg.Key.CategoryID,
                UnitID = slg.Key.UnitID,
                Stock = (int)slg.Sum(x => x.Stock)
            };
```

and I've got error "The entity or complex type 'Model.Item' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query". How to solved this?

Item entity:

```
public class Item
{
    public Guid ItemID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Guid UnitID { get; set; }
    public int Stock { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<StockLocation> StockLocations { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What part of building the LINQ query is causing you trouble?

Comment: @MitchWheat I've tried but haven't found the solution. I don't post the code because I think this is simple question so I don't feel confidence to post the code. I can do this with sql query but not LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common solution is to use a [navigation property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on the `StockLocation` entity and let EF worry about the joins for you.

Then, you can group by the `Item` itself and sum it up from the group.

```
from sl in stockLocations
group sl by sl.Item into g
select new {
    Total = g.Sum(x => x.Stock),
    Item = g.Key
};
```

The object you get back from that query is an `IQueryable<Anonymous>` where each item has a property `Total` with the total number in stock and `Item` with the all the normal properties of an item.

```
var stockInfo = from sl in stockLocations
                group sl by sl.Item into g
                select new {
                    Total = g.Sum(x => x.Stock),
                    Item = g.Key
                };

var sorted = stockInfo.OrderBy(x => x.Item.Name);
var firstItem = sorted.First();
Console.WriteLine(firstItem.Item.Name);
Console.WriteLine(firstItem.Item.Code);
//etc
```

Comment: hi @just.another.programmer, I updated the question, could you please help? Actually, there is no wrong with your answer but I've tried to create another option with join and group in order to improve my LINQ

Comment: @Willy You need to create a separate DTO for your select clause instead of using the entity itself.  If you're not sure how to do that, you should ask it as a separate question.

Comment: ok, I've created another question about mapping from entity to DTO, link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257409/how-to-bind-from-entity-to-dto-in-group-by-clause

Answer (score -2):

```
 DbContext db= new DbContext();
 var stockFromItemTable = db.Items.Sum(x=>x.Stock);
 var stockFromItemLocationTable=  db.StockLocations.Sum(y=>y.Stock);
 var totalStock =    stockFromItemLocationTable+stockFromItemTable;
```

Comment: Thanks Ish, but could you update to get all of the items stock?

Comment: Yep.Just remove the 'where' and 'find' clause from the query. I have updated the answer.

Comment: You cannot use an the `Stock` property of `Item` in your query b/c it is not mapped to the DB as the OP said.

Comment: @OP- you can map the Stock property if have not any problem with it.